# How to detect internet browser text field when adding URL address

Tags: ios, swift, url, keyboard, punctuation

I am currently developing custom keyboard in Swift 4.2. Is there any possibility to detect when a user opens Safari or other Internet browser and disables all rules that are used for correcting capital letters after the dot? Currently it always adds a space after dot in such endings as ".com", etc. Would appreciate advice very much!

Comment: Apple does not expose to you app if an other app is launched, so checking that an other is launched is not possible.

Comment: I agree that checking launched app is impossible, but maybe there is some kind of identifier how can you correctly identify that text field you are typing in is of "URL" type or something like that?